# Is there a way to distinguish the commit from home and company?

Tags: git, github

I want to distinguish the commit that I made from the company and from home.

I've already tried to change user.name and user.email in the local repository at home but the content of commit didn't change anything.
I still can't see the difference between the commit from home or company.

Comment: Sorry for asking this but to be sure we can rule it out.... you don't expect past commits to change, right? Only new commits made after the config change. Can you confirm?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by tracking whether you made the commit at home or at work?

Comment: Yeah, I understand the past commits can't change. All I want is in the future when I make a commit from home, the user name is different from the commit I make from the company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't advice you to use different values for `user.email` and `user.name` because they are properties to represent/identified the person who's contributing to the project, and in both cases, it is *you*, the fact that you're working from different locations is irrelevant.

A possible solution to achieve use purpose is to use [git notes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes)

```
git notes add  -m "From: Home"
git notes add  -m "From: Office"
```

As per [msandord comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56619653/is-there-a-way-to-distinguish-the-commit-from-home-and-company/56620829#comment99814653_56620829) this will work just with new commits, already pushed ones would need to be rebased

Comment: Since OP said they tried that, you might want to mention that this only works moving forward, since this data is part of a commit, and changing them won't change past commits without rebasing them (which would require identifying them, which is the whole point).

Answer (score -3):

Yes it is very complex and you will find yourself downloading the appstore repeatedly while trying to get it fixed and being ha ked and publicly humiliated all while doing so.